# Change standard url to specific custom URL in Concrete5

Tags: javascript, php, html, concrete5

The URL of the page is: ../nl/home/over-zitten/fitform-bewegend-zitten

I want to change the URL to: ../nl/fitmotion

Im kind of new to concrete5. Is there anyone with an idea?

Comment: what about `window.location = "url";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alias for this.
https://documentation.concrete5.org/editors/in-page-editing/the-toolbar/page-edit-drop-down/location